# Rxjs: map each element in an array field from an observable of object with another observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have a method called getTransactionDetails(id:string), and it returns an Observable of TransactionDetails object

```
getTransactionDetails(id:string):Observable<TransactionDetails>
```

The TransactionDetails object looks like this:

```
class TranscationDetails{
    id:string;
    accessCode: string;
    veggiesList: Array<Veggie>;
    meatList: Array<Meat>;
}
```

The Veggie object looks like this:

```
class Veggie{
    id: string;
    name: string;
}
```

I have another method called getVeggieSummary(veggieId: string), and it returns an Observable of VeggieSummary:

```
getVeggieSummary(veggiesId:string):Observable<VeggieSummary>
```

VeggieSummary looks like this

```
class VeggieSummary{
    id:string;
    name:string;
    color:string;
    kind:string;
}
```

I would like to call getTransactionDetails(1), and transform all the Veggies elements in the veggiesList to be VeggieSummary and return an VeggieSummary array.

This is what I have

```
getTransactionDetails(1)
.flatMap(transactionDetails=>
    transactionDetails.veggiesList
       .map(veggie=>getVeggieSummary(veggie.id)))
.subscribe(result=>
    console.log(result)
)
```

Currently, `result` is an `Observable<VeggieSummary>` and the inner observable is not even getting subscribed...

How can I have an `Observable<VeggieSummary[]>` with rxjs operators?

note: My app's angular version does not support pipe. The RxJS version is v5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to wrap the inner observable with `forkJoin`, this converts the `Observable<VeggieSummary>[]` to `Observable<VeggieSummary[]>`

```js
    getTransactionDetails(1)
      .flatMap((transactionDetails) =>
        forkJoin(
          transactionDetails.veggiesList.map((veggie) =>
            getVeggieSummary(veggie.id)
          )
        )
      )
      .subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
```

Comment: it works, thank you!, i also posted an answer below with some questions, if you can help me, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Could you try wrapping the array with `forkjoin` to see if it fixes the issue? I think currently it is returning  `Observable<VeggieSummary>[]`

```
getTransactionDetails(1)
.flatMap(transactionDetails=>
    forkJoin(transactionDetails.veggiesList
       .map(veggie=>getVeggieSummary(veggie.id))))
.subscribe(result=>
    console.log(result)
)
```

Comment: I don't see `.forkJoin` being available from getTransactionDetails(1)

Comment: sorry, my bad. Updated the answer

Comment: it works, thank you!, i also posted an answer below with some questions, if you can help me, that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

with forkjoin, this works:

```
  getTransactionDetails(1)
  .flatMap((transactionDetails) =>
    forkJoin(
      transactionDetails.veggiesList.map((veggie) =>
        getVeggieSummary(veggie.id)
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
```

I found zip with the spread operator (...) also works:

```
   getTransactionDetails(1)
  .flatMap((transactionDetails) =>
    zip(
      ...transactionDetails.veggiesList.map((veggie) =>
        getVeggieSummary(veggie.id)
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe((result) => console.log(result));
```

I learned that from another post.

But I am not sure which one to use, forkjoin or zip?
Does it matter?

I also learned about rest operator/spread operator (...) from that post.

But I still don't quite understand fully how it works in this example.

I am not sure which one I am using, am I using the rest or spread operator?

and what is it equivalent?

Comment: That's the spread operator since you're using it on an array. When you pass an array with the spread operator as a parameter it turns the individual elements into parameters. `myFunc(...[1,2,3])` is the same as `myFunc(1,2,3)`. I'd go with forkJoin since this is exactly what it's meant for.

Comment: thank you!
what is zip meant for compared to forkjoin?
should i use the spread operator in the forkjoin? why or why not?

Comment: With zip you pass separate observable paramaters, with forkjoin you pass an array of observables. That's why you needed to use the spread operator to use zip.

Comment: There are some other differences with zip , zip will support hot observable e.g continuous stream, and forkjoin only fire once